# not-normalized SQL with Hibernate/JPA

Tags: mysql, sql, hibernate, jpa

I have to deal with a not-normalized database that I can't change.
By not-normalized I mean I have two tables:

```
properties table
----------------

+----+-------+-------+
| id |  name | value |
|----|-------|-------|
|  1 | prop1 | test  |
|  2 | prop2 | test2 |
+----+-------+-------+
```

Where name is unique

```
other table
-----------

+----+-----------------------------+-------+
| id |            value            | other |
|----|-----------------------------|-------|
|  1 | ${prop1}/test               | bla   |
|  2 | ${prop1}blabla${prop2}/test | bla   |
+----+-----------------------------+-------+
```

So as you can see on other table, value column is based on properties tables. Thus the values must be (at the end)

```
${prop1}/test               => test/test
${prop1}blabla${prop2}/test => testblablatest2/test
```

I know it's really ugly, but I don't have the choice... But I would to abstract this ugly thing on my Java code.

I want to know if it's possible to create a customType that can manage this thing? A custom type where execute another SQL statement to evaluate properties inside value field and create a new object like:

```
class dynamicField {
    private String origin;
    private String evaluation;

    //GETTER & SETTER
}
```

Or other solution? (but I don't think we can create something good with this ugly SQL)

PS: The value must stay "un-evaluate" inside DB.
PS2: I can't use AOP because Entity is not managed by Spring and so I can't get access to my Service or EM. I know it's possible to inject via AspectJ + @Configurable using LTW, but I really don't want to use it.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: MySQL but it must be compatible Oracle...